# How to accept just number in redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-form

I am using `redux-form`. I want to skip 0 at the start of the number and it working fine . When user type 0 in the start it will avoid means it will start from 1-100 but I don't wont to accept alphabetic I just want to accept numeric values . Could someone please help me how to achieve this issue . Thanks

**Code**

```
export const normalizeFloat = (value) => {
  value = value.replace(/[\b(0+)]/g, "");
  const sections = value.split(".");
  return sections;
};
```

Comment: @MohammadSadeghForoughi Yes

Answer (score 0):

Set the input to a `number` type, and the browser will sort this all out for you.

`redux-form` accepts `type="number"` as a prop to the component.